# How can i configure, Payment pending order remainder auto-mail to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, email-reminders

In my site have option cash on delivery and Bank deposit, if customer placed order by cod or Bank Deposit, How can i remember to customer if order not completed with in 2 days.

Comment: i think its better to send those information in order email only.....

Comment: sorry, i couldn't get you.

Comment: once customer place an order right, than it will go mail to customer, you can include information of `2 days delay` in that email only.....

Comment: i agree your point, does possible admin get any remainder about still these order not completed because of payment pending.

Comment: for COD, once admin deliver product to customer, than only they will pay money,  `bank deposit` is manual process. so once customer paid money through `bank deposit` than for sure admin will get to know, so he can deliver that product to customer. i dont think notification is required for admin also.

Comment: for that i already said to edit or post new question with if you try url rewrite management , than how it will affect seo & how to solve that seo issue, if you dont get solution here, you can post in seo realted site : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45266/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 0):

magento default not provide this facility.
you build  extention  for this facility.
build new extension and define crontab
and check all order that are not complete within two days.
send email to that customer.

Comment: Could you pls suggest any extensions related that

Comment: Payment Reminder Notifications Pro this  extention available or  you build your own extention to use this facility